# Inconsistency in Java API

Tags: java, rounding

Why does `Math.round(double)` return `long` while `Math.floor(double)` return `double`? Is there a technical reason or is it just a historical aberration?

Comment: Same could be said of floor: "Returns the largest (closest to positive infinity) double value that is less than or equal to the argument and is equal to a mathematical integer."

Answer (score 2):

`Math.round` is *not* an opposite of `Math.floor`; [`Math.ceil`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#ceil(double)) is.

The two opposite methods, `floor` and `ceil` (short for "ceiling"), are for producing `double`s with their fraction part removed. They are consistent with each other at returning a `double`.

`round`, on the other hand, is for converting from `double` to `long` by rounding the number.

Comment: It is also worth to note that both methods preserve some specialties from `double`, like NaN, infinity or positive and negative zero and  returns the argument in these cases.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas stated here. I wasn't implying round was the opposite of floor; I could have worded the question "Why does Math.round(double) return long while Math.floor(double) and Math.ceil(double) return double?" but left out the second method for brevity. I've just found a duplicate question (with the kind of answers I was looking for) so I've marked my question as a duplicate. The answer, of course, was that I had forgotten about the method `double rint(double)` which does, in fact, go with floor and ceil consistently.